# Explicit branching rules from $G(n+m)$ to $G(n) \times G(m)$ (where $G = \operatorname{SL}$, $\operatorname{SO}$ or $\operatorname{Sp}$)

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Is there in the literature any explicit combinatorial description of the branching rules from $\operatorname{SL}(n+m)$ to $\operatorname{SL}(n) \times \operatorname{SL}(m)$, from $\operatorname{SO}(n+m)$ to $\operatorname{SO}(n) \times \operatorname{SO}(m)$, and/or from $\operatorname{Sp}(2n+2m)$ to $\operatorname{Sp}(2n) \times \operatorname{Sp}(2m)$?

To give an idea of what I mean by "explicit", for example, explicit descriptions of the branching rules from $\operatorname{SL}(n+1)$ to $\operatorname{SL}(n)$, from $\operatorname{SO}(n+1)$ to $\operatorname{SO}(n)$ and from $\operatorname{Sp}(2n+2)$ to $\operatorname{Sp}(2n)$ are well-known, due to Weyl, Murnaghan and possibly Zhelobenko. They are given for example on [the Wikipedia page for "Restricted representation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_representation), or in Knapp's "Lie groups beyond an introduction" (2d edition) in section 9.3. So ideally, I would like each of the rules from $G(n+m)$ to $G(n) \times G(m)$ to be sufficiently explicit that the rule from $G(n+1)$ to $G(n)$ basically appears as the special case $m = 1$.

For the rules I am asking about, the only thing I have found so far is [this paper by Howe, Tan and Willenbring](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0311159). However they give the branching rules only for a subset of the possible highest weights (what they call the "stable range"). Is there a description of these branching rules that also works outside the stable range?

Also, in $\operatorname{SL}(n+m)$, the subgroup $\operatorname{SL}(n) \times \operatorname{SL}(m)$ is Levi, so we can use Littelmann's branching rules in terms of the path model (see e.g. [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littelmann_path_model#Branching_rule)). However making this explicit is still a nontrivial problem of combinatorics. Even if it turns out to be an easy one, I would still rather cite its solution than have to write it up on my own.

More generally, is there anywhere a survey with a list of the branching rules for which combinatorial descriptions are known? I would expect such a list to be found, if not in the "official" published literature, then possibly on some website - e.g. [the Atlas project](http://www.liegroups.org/) (although it seems to me that they only care about infinite-dimensionnal representations - correct me if I am wrong) or somewhere in the Sage documentation (like in the vicinity of [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/root_system/branching_rules.html)).

Comment: I'm not sure there is a "clean" answer. For example, this paper discusses the branching for $G(n)$ to $G(n - 2) \times G(2)$ for various groups $G$, and the answer is not particularly elegant: https://doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1994.1064

Comment: For "rectangular shaped" representations, there are some beautiful multiplicity-free formulas which appear for instance in this paper of Okada: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869397974081

Comment: (Hi, Ilia!) This doesn't really answer your question and I'm sure you already know this, but both [LiE](http://wwwmathlabo.univ-poitiers.fr/~maavl/LiE/) and [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org/) are able to compute the branchings you describe (given a specific representation).